# Tomcat 7 Websocket isn't bind

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, websocket, tomcat7

I've a java app working perfectly on local (with Tomcat 7.0.57 and Intellij).

Today, I tried to build my app with jenkins on debian server, all my app is working except my websocket. I got an 404 eror when I execute : new WebSocket(url)

there is my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And my implementation

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.websocket.*;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import java.io.IOException;
@ServerEndpoint( value = "/sockets/publisher",
        configurator = WsConfigurator.class )
public class WebSocketPublisher {
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen( Session WsSession, EndpointConfig config ) throws IOException, PublisherException {
        //foo
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose( Session WsSession ) throws IOException {
        //foo 
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError( Session WsSession, Throwable t ) throws IOException {
        //foo
    }
}
```

If you need any other file I can provide them ( there is nothing about the socket on web.xml)

Again, it's working perfectly on localhost.

Thanks you guys

Comment: Is your app hosted at the default web context (name of the WAR) or have you specified the context in a deployment descriptor somewhere? If you have not specified it anywhere then your context path will need to include the maven version number in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the problem...

Debian tomcat package doesn't provide Websocket lib, so you need to install manually your tomcat...

Strange, but now it's working.

Thanks